# Reinitialize combo box item selected in userform

Tags: vba, ms-word, combobox, userform

How can I load in the answer (item) selected previously for a combobox in a userform.

For instance lets say I had combobox1 that has items below loaded upon initialization:

```
With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "Yes"
    .AddItem "No"
    End With
```

How could I load the selected item back in upon reinitialization of the form, so if a user selected his answer, saved, exited the userform and word doc, then reopened the userform. Basically I want the user to see their selection previously chosen to be loaded into combobox1

I have this working for textboxes attached to docvariables, but the comboboxes are attached to bookmarks.

The textboxes reinitializing code is shown below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim oVars As Object
    Set oVars = ActiveDocument.Variables
    On Error Resume Next
    TextBox1.Value = oVars("bmtitle").Value
```

Comboboxes are setup like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ComboBox1 As Range
    Set ComboBox1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("bmextension").Range
    ComboBox1.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Value

    If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Yes" Then
    ComboBox1.Text = "For additional information see CF4"
    
    End If
    
    If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "No" Then
    ComboBox1.Text = ""
    
    End If
```

Comment: You need to extract the text from the bookmarked location and set the combo box value accordingly. I hope your bookmarks enclose the text.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I just need it the combobox to say "Yes" or "No" in them, not anything related to the text. Based upon how the question was previously answered.

Comment: Then you need to save those values into the document so that you can read them again later, either using doc variables or custom properties.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt What would that look like code wise with custom properties?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/miscellaneous/storing-values-when-a-macro-ends